# facebook apps error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My face book app is http://apps.facebook.com/reelreview/, but when I click in any one of the images it shows as 'An error occurred with moviereviewforyou. Please try again later.' . Here moviereviewforyou is the name of my old face book app name. I am really confused about it. I have changed the facebook id and secrete id with my new app name as

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '*******',
  'secret' => '******',
));
```

I am not able to find out the bug in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it , it is due to the presence of old app id in the code.

Thanks